# Undefined variable _POST if called dynamically

Tags: php, post

I am creating a dynamic form handler and I want to call either `$_GET`or `$_POST` based on the forms method of submission.
In this case I am using POST.
However, the following does not work and I can not find out why.

```
function dumpMethod($method = '_POST') {
    var_dump(${$method});
    // or 
    var_dump($$method);
}
```

Both cases result in:

`Notice: Undefined variable: _POST in /path/to/script.php on line ##`

But I am sure `$_POST` is set!

Does PHP not support calling GLOBALS dynamically?

I am running version 7.1

Comment: Thank you Nigel Ren! I was not looking in the right place!